# Reverse the filter 'blur' with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, blur

In short, i've got a button, which blurs an Image on my Website. It triggers this function:

`function testblur() {imga.style.filter = 'blur(80px)';}`

Works perfectly fine. Now I want to have a second button to reverse the blur effect. I tried to achieve this by Setting the the filter back to Zero:

`function unblur1() {imga.stlye.filter = 'blur(0px)';}`

Doesn't work at all. Reloading the Image is not really an Option, because i want the Transition effect to happen. Is there a way to reverse the filter? Or another way to get the blur Animation to Play backwards?

```
<Body>
<button onClick="testblur()">blurOn</button>
<button onClick="unblur1()">blurOff</button>
<img id="img1" class="blifterimg" src="blifter/1.jpg" alt="1">
<script>
   var imga = document.getElementById('img1');
   function testblur() {imga.style.filter = 'blur(80px)';}
   function unblur1() {imga.stlye.filter = 'blur(0px)';}
</script>
</Body>
```

Comment: What “animation” are you talking about? Please don’t show single lines of code that lack context, but provide a _proper_ [mre] that illustrates your issue.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Doesn't work at all".  Does it just instantly unlbur when it should animate?  Does it just not unblur?  Does it turn blue?  What exactly do you mean by that statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. Its `imga.style` actually not `imga.stlye`

**Working Demo:**

```js
const imga = document.getElementById('imga')

function testblur() {
  imga.style.filter = 'blur(80px)';
}

function unblur1() {
  imga.style.filter = 'blur(0px)';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testblur()">Blur</button><button onclick="unblur1()">Un-Blur</button><br><br>

<img id="imga" src="https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pineapple.jpg" alt="Pineapple" width="200" height="200">
```

Comment: Don't worry, It happens sometimes. Though browser console should have shown some error. It helps in debugging purpose most of the time.

Comment: Working with Dreamweaver. It's not so fond of error checking anything, thats not HTML

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you want to add a secondary button that makes the image go back to normal after the blur. You can do this by changing your second function to imga.style.filter = 'none';

EX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button><br><br>
<button onclick="myFunctionTwo()">Reverse it</button><br><br>

<img id="myImg" src="img.jpg">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "blur(80px)";
}
function myFunctionTwo() {
  document.getElementById("myImg").style.filter = "none";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```